# Meshes made from scratch will not texture

Tags: texturing

I have made a simple mesh from scratch, starting with one vertex and tracing from an empty then extruding.
I can not get it to texture, it will only put a solid colour in.

I then tried the steps with a default cube which worked, so I deleted one face and was left with a plane - still textured ok, then deleted two more vertices, and extruded (one at a time) back to a plane again, having to make a face, back to a cuboid and it is not textured, even though the nodes are still there.
What am I missing? It is still saying the model has a uv map.

Comment: Hello :). That's because such meshes don't have a proper UV map. You need to unwrap them first (UV > Smart UV Project)

Comment: To explain more - the current UV map is basically useles, because all mapped vertices have the same location :).

Comment: Also check if your mesh isn't inside out in overlays -> face oriantation